# Group Linq Query Results in a String

Tags: c#, linq

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

I have a list of companies that offer different services.  I am trying to group the services together of a company in a string format so when I can export to excel it shows up in one column.

Right now if a company has 4 services, they will show up 4 different times in query. Which is logical, just want to group them together.

Here is what I have tried and get "A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree"

```
Services = (from cc in CharityCategories join c in Cao_Categories on cc.CategoryID equals c.CategoryID
                        join chy in CharityYears on cc.CharityYearID equals chy.CharityYearID
                        where chy.CampYearID == 5 && chy.StatusID == 1
                        group c by c.Category into cg
                        select new { Categories = cg.Key.Trim()}).Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (a, b) =>
                       {
                               if (a.Length > 0)
                                      a.Append(",");
                               a.Append(b.ToString().Split('=')[1].Replace(" }", ""));
                               return a;
                        }).ToString() ,
```

LinqPad shows the error on the line, right after `StringBuilder()`, "`Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (a, b)`"

I can get them to group in a link and when clicked, that link lists them in a format like **{ myservice = 1}** - This is why I am using `.Append`

Comment: Could you provide some raw data and expected output. The Logic in your code really does'nt help understand.

Comment: Here is what I want from query:

Company A - electric, plumbing, decks <- all on one line 

What I get now is:

Company A - electric
Company A - plumbing
Company A - decks

Answer (score 0):

use below code then change your logic accordingly, hopefully this will work

Correction in cg.Key.ToString().Trim()

```
Services = (from cc in CharityCategories
                            join c in Cao_Categories on cc.CategoryID equals c.CategoryID
                            join chy in CharityYears on cc.CharityYearID equals chy.CharityYearID
                            where chy.CampYearID == 5 && chy.StatusID == 1
                            group c by c.Category into cg
                            select new { Categories = cg.Key.ToString().Trim() }).Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (a, b) =>
                            {
                                if (a.Length > 0)
                                    a.Append(",");
                                a.Append(b.ToString().Split('=')[1].Replace(" }", ""));
                                return a;
                            }).ToString();
```

I don't know your requirement, we can correct this if you can provide exact expected result

Answer (score 0):

Well as the error says you cannot convert a lambda expression with a statement body to an expression tree. Entity framework uses expression trees to convert to sql statements. However, you can materialize the results first with (`AsEnumerable`) and then use your code with linq to objects.

```
Services = (from cc in CharityCategories
                        join c in Cao_Categories on cc.CategoryID equals c.CategoryID
                        join chy in CharityYears on cc.CharityYearID equals chy.CharityYearID
                        where chy.CampYearID == 5 && chy.StatusID == 1
                        group c by c.Category into cg
                        select new { Categories = cg.Key.ToString().Trim() })
                        .AsEnumerable()
                        .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (a, b) =>
                        {
                            if (a.Length > 0)
                                a.Append(",");
                            a.Append(b.ToString().Split('=')[1].Replace(" }", ""));
                            return a;
                        }).ToString();
```

**Important**: The aggregation will take place *after* all the rows were retrieved from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your result set can be represented in the form of the following class

```
public class Category
{
     public string Name{get;set;}
     public string Product{get;set;}
}
```

You could write the following LINQ query to get the result in the way you wished to:

```
var testList = new List <Category> {
new Category {Name = "A",Product = "decks"},
new Category {Name = "B",Product = "cards"},
new Category {Name = "C",Product = "paper"},
new Category {Name = "A",Product = "scissor"},
new Category {Name = "B",Product = "crates"},
new Category {Name = "C",Product = "rocks"}
};

var finalList = testList
    .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .Select(x => new {
        Category =x.Key,
        Items = String.Join(",", x.Select(y => y.Product))
     });
```

Thus the result set would be in the form of:

1. Category A -> decks, scissor
2. Category B-> cards,crates
3. Category C-> paper, rocks

Do mark as answer if this helps.